# Nextcloud : How to send mail through IMailer function

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, nextcloud

I am trying to write a function in my Controller to send emails through my application in nextcloud. Here is the SendUserMail function that is being used to send emails :

```
public function sendUserMail($toUserEmail, $organizations, $toDisplayName) {


    if (!$toUserEmail || !filter_var($toUserEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid email address (' . $toUserEmail . ')');
    }
   
    $emailTemplate = $this->mailer->createEMailTemplate('test@gmail.com', [
                            'owner' => 'tester',
                            'title' => 'Assign Value',
                            'link' => 'http://google.com'
                    ]);

   $emailTemplate->setSubject('App - New Activity');
                    $emailTemplate->addHeader();
                    $emailTemplate->addHeading('App - New Activity', false);
                    $emailTemplate->addBodyText('Your details have been updated');
                    $emailTemplate->addBodyText($variable);
                    $emailTemplate->addBodyText('Updated results');

   $emailTemplate->addFooter('This email is sent to you on behalf of the application. If you want to get removed from this app, contact the site administrator);

    try {
            $message = $this->mailer->createMessage();
            $message->setTo([$toUserEmail => $toDisplayName]);
            $message->useTemplate($emailTemplate);
            $this->mailer->send($message);

            return new Dataresponse(1);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->logException($e);
            throw $e;
    }
```

}

The function is written directly in controller to check but is giving a

```
[HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed 125ms]
```

error when being called from the vue js frontend using axios.

I am pretty new to app development so if anyone can guide me how can I make a function to send out emails through my app, I will be really grateful. Thank you

**EDIT 1**

Here is the Vue.js file the function where I am calling the controller and function :

```
async sendMail() {
        this.updatingType = true
        try {
            

            this.etests.toUserEmail = 'raja.hadi.ashraf@gmail.com'
            this.etests.organizations = 'test'
            this.etests.toDisplayName = 'Tester'



            const responseT = await axios.post(OC.generateUrl(`/apps/organization/api/v1/sendMail`, this.etests))

            console.log(responseT.data)




        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)

       }
       this.updatingType = false
}
```

And my routes file :

```
<?php

return [
        'resources' => [
                'note' => ['url' => '/notes'],
                'type' => ['url' => '/types'],
                'lang' => ['url' => '/langs'],
        ],
        'routes' => [
                ['name' => 'page#index', 'url' => '/', 'verb' => 'GET'],
                ['name' => 'DataRequest#sendMail', 'url' => '/api/v1/sendMail', 'verb' => 'POST'],
        ]
];
```

Response Header :

```
XHRPOST site.com/index.php/apps/organization/eusers/sendUserMail
[HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed 113ms]

    
POST
    
scheme
    https
host
    site
filename
    /index.php/apps/organization/eusers/sendUserMail
Address
    18.184.66.60:443
Status405
Method Not Allowed
VersionHTTP/1.1
Transferred1.81 KB (0 B size)

    
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2020 12:25:27 GMT

Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate

Pragma: no-cache

Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-R05vcks3SU9xczI4RVpHNnRaU25zemdUbVU0QWRSTCtkc0taeTlpc2grZz06ZHEwYUd1dE0zLzZLVitMNzRLemszQXdrckFwb09XYVpCNHZkb2EzL3pxOD0='; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; img-src * data: blob:; font-src 'self' data:; media-src *; connect-src *; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'self';

Referrer-Policy: no-referrer

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

X-Download-Options: noopen

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none

X-Robots-Tag: none

X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Content-Length: 0

Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=84

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    
Accept
    application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
    en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection
    keep-alive
Content-Length
    2
Content-Type
    application/json;charset=utf-8
Cookie
    ocuprigmi569=3cpll44d7rjoe6s0c2rtkp044n; oc_sessionPassphrase=2um4jSRlX8RW6%2F6Uham6EL7VMsg%2F7gTVtx39pEXaP8qr7%2FAPMIudEmmFBhttg9wGnGwpmfRlG2LKOji8FkyEeXNoYY6L3cJo57EJmyuM%2B0pDsxcmDFJaltZq0WBVf108; __Host-nc_sameSiteCookielax=true; __Host-nc_sameSiteCookiestrict=true; nc_username=RichardH; nc_token=Su0p2iUx8Hq9vgU8t0p1EZXEMCCzuj6H; nc_session_id=3cpll44d7rjoe6s0c2rtkp044n
Host
    site.com
Origin
    site
requesttoken
    fGmCVNlum2mUJD4OHY1dNdIP7ddWoWMqSJ6rSwV90u4=:Eh6zZYAs7lqiYk1PSLUeWuY42JM+7RdNOdfvIXAum6k=
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
```

Comment: can you share your `vue.js` file and the related routes in `web.php`?

Comment: @AndySong.. Thank you for the reply.. I have updated the questions with routes and the related function in vue.js